# Python - Remove borders from charts and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following plot:

```
dfA.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=[colorDict.get(x, '#333333') for x in 
dfA.columns],figsize=(10,8))
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 1))
```

Which displays this:

[image]

I want to remove all of the borders of the chart and legend i.e. the box around the chart (leaving the axis numbers like 2015 and 6000 etc)

All of the examples I find refer to spines and 'ax', however I have not built my chart using `fig = plt.figure()` etc.

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: `dfA.plot.bar` returns an `axes` object. Therefore you can still remove all the spines as shown in other posts.

Comment: Ok, I am an idiot. I just replace ax with plt. Apologies and ty!

Comment: Although, when I try to change the visibility of the spines I get: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'spines'

Comment: So I can remove the whole frame, but not the spines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the border of the legend by using the argument `frameon=False` in the call to `plt.legend()`.

If you only have one figure and axes active, then you can use `plt.gca()` to get the current axes. Alternatively `df.plot.bar` returns an `axes` object (which I would suggest using because `plt.gca()` might get confusing when working with multiple figures). Therefore you can set the visibility of the spines to `False`:

```
ax = dfA.plot.bar(stacked=True, color=[colorDict.get(x, '#333333') for x in 
dfA.columns],figsize=(10,8))
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 1), frameon=False)

for spine in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)

    # Color of the spines can also be set to none, suggested in the comments by ScoutEU 
    # ax.spines[spine].set_color("None")
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! :)

Comment: I also found this works for what I need to do: plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none') etc  but yours is better!

Comment: Yep that's another way. I'll update the answer to include that too